# Параллельное выполнение

Tags: c#

Есть необходимость реализовать такую штуку. Нужно что бы в параллельном потоке, например, раз в 5 секунд отправляло сообщение. Соответственно, что бы при этом приложение было рабочим, и не зависало. Перепробовал кучу всего за день, но так и не получилось ничего найти, то что бы работало. Пытался сделать через вечный цикл.

Вот на такой попытке я остановился.

```
    async Task send()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Messages.Send(false, "окей", textBox.Text, null, null,false, null, null,"256" , null, null);
        }
    }

    private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await send();
    }
```

буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для такой задачи с async/await можно не мудрить, а использовать старый-добрый [System.Threading.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx). Преимущества: не занимает лишний поток для ожидания. Помните только, что колбэк будет вызываться на потоке из пула потоков. Т.е. если у вас там есть взаимодействие с UI, то нужно переключать контекст.

```
using System.Threading;

...

private readonly TimeSpan period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);    
private Timer timer;

...

private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.timer == null)
    {
        this.timer = new Timer(SendMessage, null, this.period, this.period);
        // или так, чтоб отправка произошла немедленно
        //this.timer = new Timer(SendMessage, null, TimeSpan.Zero, this.period);
    }
}

private void SendMessage(object state)
{
    try
    {
        Messages.Send(false, "окей", text, null, null, false, null, null, "256", null, null);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // обработка возможного исключения
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как в данном случае реализовать остановку потока?

Comment: @BwehaaFox что вы имеете в виду под остановкой потока? Отключить периодическое срабатывание таймера?

Comment: ну если я просто делаю timer.Dispose(); при условии определенном, то при следующем нажатии на кнопку таймер не запускается. сделал c помошь. CancellationTokenSource cts; cts.Cancel(); timer.Dispose(); тогда Перезапускается всё нормально. При выполнении условия срабатывает cts.Cancel(); timer.Dispose(); в ином случае запускается таймер

Answer (score 2):

`async` и `Thread.Sleep` не очень дружат. Кроме того, непонятно, насколько быстрая функция `Messages.Send`.

Если быстрая, подойдёт такое:

```
async Task Send(string text)
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Messages.Send(false, "окей", text, null, null, false, null, null, "256", null, null);
    }
}

private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Send(textBox.Text);
}
```

Если медленная, то лучше так:

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => Send(textBox.Text));
}
```

Comment: Эм.. А насколько имеет смысл применять await к вечному циклу?

Comment: А если медленная, то надо написать 3 строки вместо двух.

Comment: @Qwertiy: А почему бы и нет? С await этот вечный цикл не занимает отдельный поток.

Comment: Плюс если случится исключение, оно будет доставлено в функцию `button_Click`, а не тупо проглотится. Плюсы со всех сторон.

Comment: Я не понимаю - что тут все заладили об обработке исключений? Это ведь отдельная тема, и она на совести автора. Вариант с `Task.Run` в любом случае более универсален. Даже малейшая задеркжа `Messages.Send` может произвести на конечного пользователя негативное впечатление о программе.

Comment: @z668: Дело в том, что с async/await проброс исключений выполняется бесплатно, без дополнительного кода со стороны пользователя. Но вы правы, исключения — не главное.

Comment: @z668: Вопрос по сути был в том, писать `async void button_Click(...) { await Task.Run(() => Send(textBox.Text)); }` или `void button_Click(...) { Task.Run(() => Send(textBox.Text)); }`. Второй вариант не пробрасывает исключения.

Answer (score 0):

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        Task SendMsg = new Task(() =>
        {
          while(true)
          {
            Messages.Send(false, "окей", text, null, null, false, null, null, "256", null, null);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
          }
     });

    SendMsg.Start();
}
```

Попробуй так. У меня так устанавливается связь с сервером.

Comment: Такой код проглатывает исключения. Таск нужно обязательно обзервить.